# Google Sheet Conditional Formatting Formula

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have the data shown in image, Now I want to have Red Colour of the row in which the "Effect" column has negative value and Green for the positive value. Please help me out!
Data is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wce7d.png)

Answer (score 0):

Select columns A,B,C

For red

```
=$C1<0
```

for green

```
=$C1>0
```